# Python No module name 'PhotoScan'

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the code from [this](http://www.agisoft.ru/forum/index.php?topic=2263.0) webpage.

It says that `No module name 'PhotoScan'`. I try to `pip install PhotoScan` but couldn't find it. How can I install it?

Comment: This is a thread about *scripting* in Python within the PhotoScan application. It seems that it's not a stand-alone Python module.

Answer (score 4):

The `PhotoScan` module is available to Python code running *in [PhotoScan Pro](http://agisoft.ru/products/photoscan/professional/)*, not to other Python installations. The module interfaces with the PhotoScan Pro internals

Also see the [PhotoScan Pro Python reference documentation (PDF)](http://downloads.agisoft.ru/pdf/photoscan_python_api_1_0_0.pdf).

As such, it is not something you can install outside of PhotoScan Pro. Note that the standard edition of PhotoScan does not support scripting.

Comment: So, I'm assuming then its closed source. I need to stitch images ,not manually using a tool, but automating it. Is there anything similar open-source? Had a chance to look at `Pix4d` as well, but its closed too.

Comment: I read the documentation as well, but I thought I can use as a open project. But alas!!! you made it clear that its closed. :(

Comment: The module is tied closely to the PhotoScan application; it drives the application, it is not a stand-alone project.

Comment: Is there any alternative to PhotoScan which is open-source and is good .

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: I have photoscan pro, but I cant find the python bindings to install to my python distribution and the documentation say nothing about them

Comment: @pksorensen: you don't. You run your code *in Photoscan*, which includes a Python interpreter.

Comment: hmm. I was reading the API and got the impression that i could run a script outside. Was hoping for automating the process from python bindings

Answer (score 1):

Since some versions it is possible to use Metashape (PhotoScan) Python module without the original applications: https://agisoft.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/31000148930-how-to-install-metashape-stand-alone-python-module
However, the valid license is still required.